# Eclipse : Updating appcompat_v7

Tags: android, eclipse

As my checking the appcompat folder in my project , there is some support library file into this project , anddroid-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar , i updated my support library into sdk manager and i want update them in my project also, how should i do?

Comment: do you have appcompat_v7 directory under projects?

Comment: then there must be an error jar mismatch fix dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Inside project directory appcompat_v7 --> libs --> You will find two jar files, anddroid-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar, Copy them
Go to your project --> libs --> Paste both files here or the one which is showing Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
. Clean Build, your project.
This will put the newly updated jar files to your libs folder of the project. Because the problem was it is not updated in the proj.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.
Right click on project,android tool,add support library,and accept terms and download updates,eclips will update your support libraries on project

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same error and came accross with following solution:

1. Close your actual workspace with your DEVELOPMENT project
2. Create new workspace
3. Create new Android TEST project. This will automatically create appcompat_v7 with Android last updated version.
4. Go to your DEVELOPMENT project workspace PATH, (not into Eclipse, The workspace directory)
5. Delete appcompat_v7
6. Go to your Android TEST project workspace PATH
7. Copy this appcompat_v7
8. Paste into your DEVELOPMENT project workspace PATH
9. Now Open Eclipse with your DEVELOPMENT project workspace

FIXED